# How to query UCD-SNMP-MIB using snmpwalk

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have installed MRTG, snmpd, snmpwalk, snmpget on windows 2003 server;
I have configured an SNMP agent on 192.168.100.88

When I run this SNMP walk command then I am getting empty response for UCD-SNMP-MIB

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c community 192.168.100.88  .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4 
End of MIB
```

I also see ...

```
snmpget -v1 -c community 192.168.100.88 memAvailReal.0
Error in packet
Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
Failed object: UCD-SNMP-MIB::memAvailReal.0
```

What am I missing? Should I install UCD-SNMP-MIB on host or client, and how ?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the OID(memAvailReal.0) that you are passing. Try with the OID(dotted integers) instead of name.

If the same error "no such name" comes again, please confirm that the OID is supported by the device.

**P.S:** *"no such name"* which means no such object present in the device to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (modify to your needs such as network info)

https://gist.github.com/2848189

create a backup of your existing snmpd.conf then reload snmpd and try your snmpwalk again